# How to resolve peer, orderer and CA hostnames for REST API on Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, hyperledger-fabric, hosts

So we have setup a multi-org, multi-channel fabric v2.2 network on AWS EC2. For testing from local, we had defined the "/etc/hosts" file for resolving the hostnames of peers, orderers and certificate authorities like following:

**/etc/hosts**

```
[ec2-public-ip]   peer0.org1.com
[ec2-public-ip]   orderer0.orderer.com
[ec2-public-ip]   ca.org1.com
```

And the connection profile looked like:

**ccp-org1.json**

```
{
    "name" : "org1",
    "version" : "1.0.0",
    "client" : {
        "organization" : "org1",
        "connection" : {
            "timeout" : {
                "peer" : {
                    "endorser" : "300"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "organizations" : {
        "tracexOrg" : {
            "mspid" : "org1MSP",
            "peers" : [ 
                "peer0.org1.com"
            ],
            "certificateAuthorities" : [ 
                "ca.org1.com"
            ]
        }
    },
    "peers" : {
        "peer0.tracextech.com" : {
            "url" : "grpcs://[ec2-public-ip]:7051",
            "tlsCACerts" : {
                "pem" : "pem-file"
            },
            "grpcOptions" : {
                "ssl-target-name-override" : "peer0.org1.com",
                "hostnameOverride" : "peer0.org1.com"
            }
        }
    },
    "certificateAuthorities" : {
        "ca.org1.com" : {
            "url" : "https://[ec2-public-ip]:7054",
            "caName" : "ca.org1.com",
            "tlsCACerts" : {
                "pem" : [ 
                    "pem-file"
                ]
            },
            "httpOptions" : {
                "verify" : false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But now, we have deployed our express API over Lambda, and I'm unable to figure out how will Lambda resolve the private hostnames? Is there a way to define "etc/hosts" file for Lambda also or is there some other procedure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer:

So AWS has a service in Route 53 for [Private Hosted Zones](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-private.html) that allow you to define custom DNS entries for a domain name say "example.com", and you can associate that zone to a particular VPC in which your Fabric instance is located.
You can then define dns entries for peer, orderers, etc. in that private zone to resolve to the IP of the Fabric instance. Make sure you also set up Lambda in a private subnet in that VPC, et voila!